# How to process the .wav file to get meaningful information like the number of inhales/exhales

Tags: fft, filters, signal-analysis, python, sound

[image]
The plot of the data from the wav file.

Link to the sound file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxAPlY66uX7qWWtDZUw3WkpjSGs&authuser=0

Also the FFT plot is like this[image]

I am new to the field of digital signal processing.

I have a `.wav` file in which I have recorded the breathing sound in a closed environment. I am trying to figure out what kind of technique I can apply to process the `.wav` file to get meaningful information like the number of inhales/exhales.

I have read the file in python using `Scipy` library and plotted the data. Also I have applied Fast Fourier Transformation to plot the frequency amplitudes. At this point I am feeling lost, how could I get meaningful information like the number of exhales/inhales?

Comment: it might be helpful to others if you showed your plots, and maybe even uploaded your sound clip **edit** actually you may not have enough points to do that. You can put links in your description and maybe someone nice will embed them into your question

Comment: I have edited the initial post to be give out more information.

Comment: your google link to the wave file is private. you might have to make it public

Comment: Sorry about that : Here is the link again
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAPlY66uX7qWWtDZUw3WkpjSGs/view?usp=sharing